# Passing a Model Object to a Function

Tags: python, machine-learning, catboost

The function below essentially takes a ML model (in this case CatBoost, but it can be a Random Forest or XGBoost), and performs standard ML tasks.

```
def run_final_model(model,params,X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test):
    model.final = model(**params)
    model.fitted =  model.final.fit(X_train,y_train)
    y_pred = model.predict(y_test)
    print('Generalization Score: '+ round(accuracy_score(y_pred,y_test),1))
    print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))

## Calling the Function that Fits,Predicts and Output the Confusion Matrix Results
run_final_model(,catboost_best_params,X_train_prepared,X_test_prepared,y_train,y_test)
```

However, I'm getting an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\FRANCI~1.COL\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15116/15558614.py in <module>
      1 ## Calling the Function that Fits,Predicts and Output the Confusion Matrix Results
      2 
----> 3 run_final_model(CatBoostClassifier(),catboost_best_params,X_train_prepared,X_test_prepared,y_train,y_test)

C:\Users\FRANCI~1.COL\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15116/3739208688.py in run_final_model(model, params, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
      1 def run_final_model(model,params,X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test):
----> 2     model.final = model(**params)
      3     model.fitted =  model.final.fit(X_train,y_train)
      4     y_pred = model.predict(y_test)
      5 

TypeError: 'CatBoostClassifier' object is not callable
```

I know is because somehow I have to be able to call `CatBoostClassifier`, and in this case I'm passing an object that is stored. Obviously, I have coded a function that simply strips the name of the model, and included an if so it will call the model. However, there should be a more elegant solution, so I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: remove parenthesis to pass a class instead of an instance: `run_final_model(CatBoostClassifier, ...)`

Comment: Also, unlike R, Python doesn't support dots in variable names. Assigning stuff to `model.final` will set an instance/class property and might lead to unintended side effects; `model_final` would be a more appropriate name for this variable